# OpenCL optimization and apparnt PCI bus limitations?

Tags: optimization, opencl, jogl

I'm writing a program using JOGL/openCL to utilize the GPU.  I have code that kicks in when we work with data sizes which is suppose to detect the available memory on the GPU.  If there is insufficient memory on the GPU to process the entire calculation at once it will break the process up into sub process with X number of frames which utilizes less then the max GPU global memory to store.

I had expected that using the maximum possible value of X would give me the largest speed up by minimizing the number of kernels used.  Instead I found using a smaller group (X/2 or X/4) gives me better speeds.  I'm trying to figure out why breaking the GPU processing into smaller groups rather then having the GPU process the maximum amount it can handle at one time gives me a speed increase; and how I can optimize to figure out what the best value of X is.

My current tests have been running on a GPU kernel which uses very little processing power (both kernels decimate output by selecting part of input and returning it)  However, I am fairly certain the same effects occur when I activate all kernels which do a larger degree of processing on the value before returning.

Comment: just to check i understood - you're saying that when you split the task into more *sequential* jobs, it works more quickly?  so you are using smaller jobs, but are *not* submitting them in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing more sequential jobs.  I'm also using two very simple kernels (both decimate data and nothing else) as tests.  It seems as if most of the more complicated optimizations wouldn't apply to such a simple kernel that doesn't use local memory, multiple registers, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, it's complicated.  There are many factors at play.  These include (but are not limited to):

1. Amount of local memory you are using.
2. Amount of private memory you are using.
3. A limit on the max number of work groups the Symmetric Multiprocessor is able to handle at once.
4. Exceeding register limits, causing memory access slow-down.
5. And many more...

I recommend you check out the following link:

http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece498/al/textbook/Chapter5-CudaPerformance.pdf

In particular, check out section **5.3. Dynamic Partitioning of SM Resources**.  This text is meant to be general purpose, but uses CUDA for its examples.  However, the concepts still apply just the same to OpenCL.

This text comes from the following book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Massively-Parallel-Processors-Hands-/dp/0123814723/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1314279939&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123814723)

For what its worth, I found this book to be very informative.  It will give you a deeper understanding of the hardware that will allow you to answer questions like this.

Comment: can't comment on the book, but an explanation related to memory access sounds right to me.  somehow by keeping the job small, you must be using limited resources more efficiently.

Comment: just updating.  I think the issue may be with coalescing.  I'm reducing an array by taking ever Xth element and placing it in a new shrunken array.  I think the memory access pattern is preventing any coalescing of data and hurting me.  I'm just not sure that I would get that drastic a slow down even from an unfavorable memory usage.  I am running at half the speed of the GPU on the same processing batch once this reduction kernel kicks in; which means a major slow down is being caused by it.  If I can't fix it I'll have to move the processing to the CPU

Comment: but why would that depend on the amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

PCI-e are full duplex bi-directional.  i *think* that means you can write as you read.  in which case, if you're doing very little processing, you may be seeing a gain because you're overlappings reads with writes.

consider a total size of N.  in one work unit you do:

- write N
- process N
- read N

total time proportional to: process N, transfer 2N

if you split this in two with parallel read/write you can get:

- write N/2
- process N/2
- read N/2 and write N/2
- process N/2
- read N/2

total time proportional to: process N, transfer 3N/2 (saving N/2 transfer time)